# A Cross Report on Campaign Members

Tags: reporting

I want to do a join report on campaign members of two separate campaigns. I want to join them on the "email" field, or some other specified criteria. (cm1.email = cm2.email) and see the results.

An example: overlap of attendees / registrants of an event A and event B (those associated with both events, each event being a campaign).

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: worth asking this on salesforce success forum where there are more end users and sysads

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create such a report by creating a report type "contacts with campaign history and campaign members"

When you then create a matrix report with this report type, you'll be able to see campaigns in columns and members in rows. And of course, it's possible to show other fields, summarize rows and colums, drill down, etc.

A simple screenshot created this way showing the record count of contacts versus campaigns:

[image]